# How do I add additional directories to the shortcuts in Nautilus left pane?

Tags: menu

When I click on "applications" on the top menu bar, and then select the "files" icon, Nautilus (the default file manager) is opened.

In Nautilus, the left pane has a list of directories (shortcuts), and the right pane has a list of files.

How do I add a few additional directory names to the left pane?

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.1.

Comment: my apologies. After 60 years of programming, I am used to provide full details. Since I have only posted a few questions, I was not aware how this system would reformat my text. It was a lot more readable before it was mangled. The primary question is in the title.

Comment: Artur, Thank you. much more readable. and you even answered one of my questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CTRL + D` in specific directory, will pin it to left panel.

Comment: Miocik Thank you, it would never have occured to me to use CTL-D as that means in Communications "End-of-Transmission"